# Rails manipulate a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I have a string that looks like this:

```
  ["7zip", "SysInternals", "Office", "PDF-Creator", ""]
```

I want to to change it to looks like this:

```
 http://www.domain.com/7zip,office,pdf-creator
```

Do you know how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a string, it's an Array object (of strings).

Call `.join(',')` on it.

`["7zip", "SysInternals", "Office", "PDF-Creator", ""].join(',')`

If you want to get rid of the empty strings so you don't have extra commas,

`["7zip", "SysInternals", "Office", "PDF-Creator", ""].reject{ |c| c.empty? }.join(',')`

Based on your question, it looks like you're dropping "SysInternals" for some reason. If that was intentional, you'll need to reject that one as well;

`["7zip", "SysInternals", "Office", "PDF-Creator", ""].reject{ |c| c.empty? || c == "SysInternals"  }.join(',')`

If you have a more general way of selecting or rejecting certain items in the array, it would be best to use that. You could also create a method to clean it up.

```
def reject_item?( item )
  item.empty? || item == "SysInternals"
end

["7zip", "SysInternals", "Office", "PDF-Creator", ""].reject{ |c| reject_item?(c) }.join(',')
```

And finally, if you want to downcase the values, you'll need to do just that!

```
["7zip", "SysInternals", "Office", "PDF-Creator", ""].reject{ |c| reject_item?(c) }.collect{ |c| c.downcase }.join(',')
```

You should read about the [Array class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html), specifically [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html)#[collect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-collect), [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html)#[reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-reject) and [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html)#[join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-join)

Comment: That was an array. But serialized it to a string to save it to my sqllite. Oh, i just forgot sysinternals. that was my error